# x-api-key in header still gives Forbidden response (AWS lambda function)

Tags: rest, aws-lambda, api-key

I have a Lambda function on AWS for which I have created a trigger with Security. I set the url (`$url`) to be the API endpoint listed in the "triggers" section of the lambda function, and the x-api-key (instead of `my_api_key` below) to be the one listed in the trigger "API key".

However, if I try to make a simple call to the lambda function like so:

```
           $url = "https://abcd1234.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/default/lambda_function_name";

           $header = array(
               "Content-Type" => "application/json",
               "Accept" => "application/json",
               "x-api-key" => "my_api_key",
           );
           
           $data = array(
             "email_address" => $_POST['email'],
           );
           
           $curl = curl_init();
           curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
           curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
           curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, json_encode($header));
           curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

           $result = curl_exec($curl);
           curl_close($curl);
```

I obtain the response "Forbidden".

What is the issue here?
Is there some AWS configuration I need to change?
Or is the syntax or place to add the x-api-key wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Maithreya

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are connecting to AWS API Gateway. Your endpoint URL must include the stage and resource, i.e.:

https://abcd1234.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/send_email_alert

Calling the API gateway base endpoint URL will result in this error.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your response! My api endpoint looks like this: https://abcd1234.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/default/lambda_function_name. I notice that you have prod whereas I have default. What does that mean? (Additionally, I should add that if I remove API key and keep an open endpoint, I am able to get the API to work. Does the endpoint have to be in a different format when you put an API key requirement?)

Comment: (the dots after default are because stackoverflow truncated it, it should read /default/lambda_function/name)

Comment: @MaithreyaSitaraman but the endpoint is clearly wrong, eg "https:my_endpoint" you're missing the slashes. Please edit your question with a realistic example (doesn't have to work just indicate exactly how you have it setup)

Comment: @JeremyThompson ok will add slashes and more realistic, thanks

Comment: It doesn't matter what you call your "stage" in API Gateway, if you called it "default" then great. After the stage name should be the "resource" you created to receive the request via a POST, GET, etc. Usually the method is named for what it does (i.e. adduser, sendalert, etc.), and that method calls the Lambda function. As for the resource, did you create a resource in API Gateway named after your lambda function. I just want to make sure we understand what you setup in API Gateway, and we only have your example URL to go by.